# qt5 build with cmake on window: ERROR: C++11 <random> is required and is missing or failed to compile

Tags: cmake, qt5

My env:

Qt source: dev branch

cmake version: 3.18.4.0

os: windows

Build step:

```
cd qt_source
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Then error raised:

```
ERROR: C++11 <random> is required and is missing or failed to compile.
ERROR: detected a std::atomic implementation that fails for function pointers.  Please apply the patch corresponding to your Standard Library vendor, found in qtbase/config.tests/atomicfptr
```

How can I debug this?

Update on 2020/10/26:

I used the `vcpkg install qt5` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use a bit more stable Qt branch, e.g. `5.15.1` or `5.12`, otherwise you should be aware that `dev` branch is on-going development of new features and Qt 6 (as of 01/11/2019), and all bug fixes that are not only relevant for Qt 5 (as of 15/05/2020).

From my practical experience, current `dev` branch always need some tricks to use and brings lots of problems. If you still need to test some feature that is available only in `dev` -- consider switch to some stable branch and cherry-pick changes you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to build Qt itself from sources with Visual Studio 16 2019 generator. Turned out, [it is not supported](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89435?focusedCommentId=542553&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-542553) (*yet?*), so I had to use Ninja generator instead (*and set C/C++ compiler to `cl.exe`*) - then the configuration and build went fine.

So perhaps that is the case with building projects too - you should check if you are using Ninja (*and switch to it if not*).